# Network Manager update has triggered network pauses

Tags: release-juno, updates, networking

With the ath9k driver, the recent Network Manager (1.10.14) update creates "pauses" in applications that use the network without buffering.  In Terminal, using, say, ssh, one will type something and wait ten seconds for all of it to echo.  Or eboard, a chess (FICS) interface, will show no moves and then "jump" forward, as moves were made but you couldn't see them until the "freeze" interval was over.  The pauses are irregular in both interval and duration.   Zero issues for months, then the update, and *splat*.  journalctl -u NetworkManager shows nothing unusual.